# Are there any pictures of a sample accurate spectrogram on the web or in books?

Tags: frequency-spectrum, spectrogram

I programmed a sample accurate spectrogram some time ago and i still have never seen a picture of another one. It's interesting maths, i was told it's trivial, so why has no one else posted research on sample accurate sgrams on the internet? Can you find one. Here is a pic of my version: 
[image: Zoom in of 1ms of sound in mid frequencies]

this is the same program without the zoom and in 2d Mode:

[image]

Comment: Oh Thank you Antoine! in Wigner-Ville results i found this kind of spectrogram, which is of the kind of detail resolution i am researching, this is what a sonogram should resemble, and i find these views of sound fascinating: http://www.freeware-download.com/screenshots/2/12482-a.jpg

Comment: Indeed, I'm in another area now but this is the kind of problem that got me into signal processing. Have fun :)

Comment: What do you mean by "sample accurate spectrogram"?

Comment: I meant a spectrogram of the the same sample resolution as the audio file. input a 1 second sound with 22k samples, output a spectrogram with 22k values on y axis.

Comment: @ufomorace Hum then  I may have misled you. With a signal with 22k values, you may perfectly have a "22k values" spectrogram. It is not related with accuracy.  For instance, you could use a 1-sample step and a 5k-samples length window, your spectrogram would have 22k values on y axis but a very poor temporal resolution (yet an exelent frequency resolution). Do you know about uncertainty principle and time-frequency tradeoff ?

Comment: I see, do you mean that i could use FFT, where the window is advanced every time by one sample, to make a spectrogram with one value for every sample? i figure that it's more precise with Wigman Ville transform. Yes i understand the time-frequency tradeoff.

Comment: "I see, do you mean that i could use FFT, where the window is advanced every time by one sample, to make a spectrogram with one value for every sample?" - Yes. Indeed Wigner-ville transform gives a better resolution, but it comes at the price of artificact in the spectrogram.

Comment: Thanks. I see very very major artifacts in the Wigner-Ville transform compared to other high res sonograms. Normally the audio is dismantled into many sine waves that run concurrently along the x-axis and merge and mix upwards on the y-axis. A clear spectrogram should show the actual peaks and troughs of all the sine frequencies composing a sound, so that the peaks of the sonogram at 1khz are 10 times longer periods than at 10khz. In Wigner-Ville digram that i have seen, all the patterns of all the frequencies have the same time variations. it is strange. i'll write a question about it.

Comment: I have been told that the FFT used in this way will mean that every sample will be a low resolution estimation based on the size of the window around it. Do you think there are any picture of single sample iterated FFT on the internet so that i can see an example, if there is some research on them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Producing accurate time-frequency analysis is an area of research. Some pointers are : Wigner-Ville transformation, re-allocation methods, wavelets.

Comment: i found an implementation program here which uses Wigner Ville transformation called sonogram 4 here. http://www.christoph-lauer.de/sonogram

Comment: Thanks a lot i have to test FFT implementation with single sample increments because Wigner Ville seems to be not very clear and rather slow. I did a detailed comparison study of a birdcall and here is the result: http://s29.postimg.org/th7pjz66v/sonogram_study.jpg